# PHP forgot password

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a forgot password page for the user in PHP but when I enter the code the page just reloads and nothing else happens . No errors nothing .

```
if($submit){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];

    $email_check = mysqli_query($conn ,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='" . $email. "'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($email_check);

    if($count != 0 ){
        // generate a new password
        $random = rand(72891, 92729);
        $new_password = $random;

        $email_password = $new_password;

        $new_password = password_hash($new_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 14));         

        $new_password = password_hash($new_password);

        mysqli_query("update users set pw='" . $new_password. "' WHERE email='" . $email. "'");

        $subject = "Login information";
        $message = "Your password has been changed to $email_password";
        $from = "From: example.me";

        mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Your new password has been sent to you";
    } else {
        echo"This email does not exists";
    }
}
```

Comment: you're double hashing and never queried the update.

Comment: in what condition(s) will `$submit` have a truthy value? have you ensured it is truthy?

Comment: No errors; that's because you didn't check for them. Once your code below the condition kicks in, you'll see what you did wrong; a lot.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$email_password` is `$random = rand(72891, 92729);` which is just a random number.

Comment: @MichaelCoker yeah my mistake. Nonetheless, my comment about their double hashing is valid. I deleted my comment about that.

Comment: A: what this question needs is a total rewrite and have the user choose their own password in a reset with a unique/one time token and hash it "once", not twice and shouldn't be mailed their password and for a lot of reasons. The update again; will not happen here.

Answer (score 2):

I will tell you exactly what is going on with your code here.

**Part 1:**

```
if($submit){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];
```

- `$submit = $_POST['submit'];` is assigned after your opening `if($submit)`.
- Result with [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php): Undefined submit variable.

**Part 2:**

```
$new_password = password_hash($new_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 14));         
$new_password = password_hash($new_password);
```

You're trying to double hash which won't give you any added benefits and will also fail when trying to [verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) it later. What happened here is that the second one failed and shouldn't even be used at all.

*Why did it fail?* Because, it's missing a parameter.

- Result:

  > Warning: password_hash() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /path/to/file.php on line x
- Added result: An empty password row (when the UPDATE happens. See "Part 3").

**Part 3:**

```
mysqli_query("update users set pw='" . $new_password. "' WHERE email='" . $email. "'");
```

The query doesn't contain a database connection for it.

- Result:

  > Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /path/to/file.php on line x

In regards to your variables and the connection API used is unknown, so you will have to make sure that you are using the same MySQL API to connect with, and that your variables and POST arrays contain values.

Error reporting will help you, as will checking for errors on the query.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

**Final notes:**

Use a prepared statement instead, it's much safer

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Also; you should let the user choose their own password in a reset with a unique/one time token and hash it "once", not twice and shouldn't be mailed their password and for a lot of reasons. This is best common practice. If the user's email account ever gets compromised and they haven't deleted the email containing their login password, then they are at risk in having their login account also being compromised.

Answer (score 0):

`$submit` is not declared until after the validation of your `if` statement.

Validate using another variable.  Good place to start is to check and see if `$_POST` is submitted

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

To email the password change

```
$message = "Your password has been changed to $email_password";
```

to

```
$message = "Your password has been changed to {$email_password}";
```

The password stored in the DB has been hashed twice.  **Remove**

```
$new_password = password_hash($new_password);
```

The SQL needs to be executed to update the password hash in the database.

```
$sql = "update users set pw='" . $new_password. "' WHERE email='" . $email. "'";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   echo "Password updated successfully";
} else {
   echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: you also missed a lot of stuff

Comment: @Fred-ii please elaborate?  isn't the question why no errors?

Comment: I'm afraid you fell into a very deep rabbit hole. Have look at their code again and very carefully. Then, look at the comments I left under their question. As you can tell, I did not post an answer for this because of all that. You'll see what I mean (I hope).

Comment: *"To email the password change

$message = "Your password has been changed to $email_password";"* - what's wrong with that? Variables evaluate inside double quotes.

Comment: @Fred-ii $email_password is loaded with $random via $new_password.  Then remains untouched.  Then $new_passord is hashed.  So $email_password should contain the user readable value.  This is quiet a lot.

Comment: yes, it's hashed alright; twice. How do you think `password_verify()` will react? You also didn't respond to their update.

Comment: I can't comment on design criteria.  Your right that the password should be user settable.  But a random password is valid.  Might not be secure or friendly but valid none the less.   To this I have achieved the goal.

Comment: again; look at the update query. I said it countless times.

Answer (score -1):

You're testing for `$submit` but defining `$submit` inside of the test, so `$submit` likely isn't evaluating as true.

Try changing the outer `if ($submit)` to `if (!empty($_POST))`

Comment: you missed a lot of stuff and it will not solve this question.